# Terminology: opposite of "zero copy"?

Tags: terminology, sendfile, zero-copy

We're benchmarking some code that we've converted to use sendfile(), the linux zero-copy system call.  What's the term for the traditional read()/write() loop that sendfile() replaces?  I.e., in our report I want to say "zerocopy is X millisecs, and ??? is Y millisecs."  What word/phrase should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Traditional data copying approach"

Answer (score 1):

`Programmed I/O (PIO)` would be appropriate, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Just "copy"?......